# Variable speed for jQuery Cycle plugin horizontal slider

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-cycle

I'm using jQuery Cycle plugin to create a very simple slideshow.

Below the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var slideshow = $('#slider').cycle({

    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    speed: 500,
    timeout: 8000,
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next',
autostop: false 
    });
});
```

And the part of HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
<img class="slide" src="header/slider/images/FOTO_SCORRE2.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="slide" src="header/slider/images/FOTO_SCORRE3.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="slide" src="header/slider/images/FOTO_SCORRE4.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="slide" src="header/slider/images/FOTO_SCORRE5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

My question is: how can I vary the speed of slide, during the image's change? I would like the image accelerates from zero speed to a fixed max speed, and from mid transition decelerates to zero.

It's possible in a simple way?

Comment: The technical name for what your asking about is 'Easing' See many examples here http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html and here http://james.padolsey.com/demos/jquery/easing/. it appears that the Cycle plugin has easing hooks that you can set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical name for what your asking about is 'Easing' See many examples [jQuery UI Easing examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html) and [Other easing Styles](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/jquery/easing). it appears that the Cycle plugin has easing hooks that you can set.